# How would you "connect" many independent graphs maintaining backpressure between them?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

Continuing series of questions about `akka-streams` I have another problem.

**Variables:**

- Single http client flow with throttling
- Multiple other flows that want to use first flow simultaneously

**Goal:**

Single http flow is flow that makes requests to particular API that limits number of calls to it. Otherwise it bans me. Thus it's very important to maintain rate of request regardless of how many clients in my code use it.

There are number of other flows that want to make requests to mentioned API but I'd like to have backpressure from http flow. Normally you connect whole thing to one graph and it works. But it my case I have multiple graphs.

How would you solve it ?

**My attempt to solve it:**

I use `Source.queue` for http flow so that I can queue http requests and have throttling. Problem is that `Future` from `SourceQueue.offer` fails if I exceed number of requests. Thus somehow I need to "reoffer" when previously offered event completes. Thus modified `Future` from `SourceQueue` would backpressure other graphs (inside their `mapAsync`) that make http requests.

Here is how I implemented it

```
object Main {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("root")
  implicit val executor = system.dispatcher
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  private val queueHttp = Source.queue[(String, Promise[String])](2, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
    .throttle(1, FiniteDuration(1000, MILLISECONDS), 1, ThrottleMode.Shaping)
    .mapAsync(4) {
      case (text, promise) =>
        // Simulate delay of http request
        val delay = (Random.nextDouble() * 1000 / 2).toLong
        Thread.sleep(delay)
        Future.successful(text -> promise)
    }
    .toMat(Sink.foreach({
      case (text, p) =>
        p.success(text)
    }))(Keep.left)
    .run

  val futureDeque = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque[Future[String]]()

  def sendRequest(value: String): Future[String] = {

    val p = Promise[String]()
    val offerFuture = queueHttp.offer(value -> p)

    def addToQueue(future: Future[String]): Future[String] = {
      futureDeque.addLast(future)
      future.onComplete {
        case _ => futureDeque.remove(future)
      }
      future
    }

    offerFuture.flatMap {
      case QueueOfferResult.Enqueued =>
        addToQueue(p.future)
    }.recoverWith {
      case ex =>
        val first = futureDeque.pollFirst()
        if (first != null)
          addToQueue(first.flatMap(_ => sendRequest(value)))
        else
          sendRequest(value)
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val allFutures = for (v <- 0 until 15)
      yield {
        val res = sendRequest(s"Text $v")
        res.onSuccess {
          case text =>
            println("> " + text)
        }
        res
      }

    Future.sequence(allFutures).onComplete {
      case Success(text) =>
        println(s">>> TOTAL: ${text.length} [in queue: ${futureDeque.size()}]")
        system.terminate()
      case Failure(ex) =>
        ex.printStackTrace()
        system.terminate()
    }

    Await.result(system.whenTerminated, Duration.Inf)
  }
}
```

Disadvantage of this solution is that I have locking on `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` which is probably not that bad for rate of 1 request per second but still.

How would you solve this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have an open ticket (https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/19478) and some ideas for a "Hub" stage which would allow for dynamically combining streams, but I'm afraid I cannot give you any estimate for when it will be done.

So that is how we, in the Akka team, would solve the task. ;)